# Redirect back to Workflow Status page after Approving task in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-designer

Currently I have a document workflow setup to send task participants an email with a given task to review and approve a document. In the email I included a link to the page where they can approve/reject the document. My problem, however, is that once users click accept or reject on the form, it redirects them to the task list for the SharePoint site, which I do not want.

Instead, I want them to be redirected back to the Workflow Status Page for the document they are approving. What I've tried is setting the URL to [%Current Task:Form_URN%]&Source=[%Workflow Context:Workflow Status URL%] in the String Builder because I though it would that would just redirect the user back to whatever the source URL was, but that didn't work. I received an error that had to do with the Workflow Instance ID.

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Is this solution possible. And if so, can it be implemented using SPD and not with code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19d59eef-b880-4c22-a279-5a738cd2c4fc/sharepoint-2013-workflow-task-approvereject-redirect-where-users-end-up-after-approving-or?forum=sharepointgeneral